# How to check if column equals a value and do somthing if true?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I have an app store where users can select the apps that they want to display on their home screen and if they select the app, it will change the value in the column for that app from 0 to 1 in the row associated with their email. I want to check if that app equals 1 and display the code on the page for that app.

Right now I am trying to SELECT from the database where the app is located and say that if that variable is equal to 1 then do something

```
$netflix = "SELECT netflix FROM video WHERE email='$videoemail'";
if($netflix == 1) {
  $netflixapp = '<a href="iframes/video/netflix.html"><div class="library-object video"><img src="https://yt3.ggpht.com/a-/AAuE7mAl-SFLIFoYxNhmk3m6xPT-d1oTec2sEvxThw=s900-mo-c-c0xffffffff-rj-k-no"><p class="object-info ">Netflix<p /></div></a>';
}
```

And in the body I have

```
<?PHP echo $netflixapp; ?>
```

to echo the variable if it exists

It is not working, so any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Also, $videoemail is equal to $_SESSION['email']

Comment: What is the column name where the 0 or 1 switch is located?

Comment: Where's your code that actually executes the query against the database? Something like $sql = ""SELECT netflix FROM video WHERE email='$videoemail'";
$result = $conn->query($sql); And then inspect the result.

Comment: the column name is netflix. and then there are several other columns for each app, such as plex or slingtv

Comment: And the code that interacts with the database is the $netflix variable

Comment: OK, so you set the variable netflix equal to "SELECT netflix FROM video WHERE email='$videoemail'"; and then immediately check if its value is 1? What?